# What happened to sourcedstring fom NLTK 2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

`sourcedstring` was a module in NLTK 2.0 that provided strings that "knew" what offsets in a document the string came from, and retained those offsets across substring and copying operations.

The module was removed ages ago.
You can see it [on this old page](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sourcedstring.html).

What should I do with my (old) code that uses it? Is there an obvious replacement?